# same text size in both webview and textview

Tags: android, webview, textview, text-size

I have used both textview and Webview in my application. The problem is ,the font size of webview and textview varies on each mobile.
I added the following css code in the head tag of html

```
body {
font-size: 1.04em;
text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
/* CSS for high-density screens */
body {
font-size: 0.89em;
}
}

@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0) {
/* CSS for extra high-density screens */
body {
font-size: 0.94em;
}
}
```

and i gave 14 sp as text size for Textview.
I know this question was asked earlier.But i didn't find any solution there.
Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an ideal solution but it was the only thing that works with me.

```
webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(14);  // between 1 and 72, default is 16.
```

Just try different numbers till you get the same text size

Hope it works.

Comment: This sucks; The size is depending on the densitity